# log file parsing with boost

Tags: c++, json, parsing, boost

I need to parse logfile in C++. I have this sample of string from this file:

```
[2020-08-23 19:19:29.137] [exchange_tools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212350,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187624,"prev_seq_num": 111529187575,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
```

From this JSON I need: "type", "event_time", "asks", "bids".

My current solution is: for each string in file delete first symbols from begin to "Object: " on python.

```
{"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212350,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187624,"prev_seq_num": 111529187575,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
```

Then I save is like JSON file, read for each string in C++:

```
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::ifstream json_in("outfile.json");
    std::string line_json;

    while (std::getline(json_in, line_json)) {

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << line_json;

        boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
        std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("type") << std::endl;

    }
```

It works for me, but I want to parse log file in C++ (boost) without using python. How can i do it?

Comment: @JaMiT I thought so at first, but then I came up with the idea to make a "template" of a string in a regular expression. Perhaps it would simplify the search. But I think yes, the easiest way is to delete the first characters using erase, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't mis-use Property Tree for JSON or XML support. Use Boost JSON instead.

Secondly, of course you can do the string manipulation in C++. Here's an example that should be easy to extend:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

struct Record {
    std::string time, source, level, msg;
};
using Records = std::vector<Record>;
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Record, time, source, level, msg)

namespace Parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto bracketed = rule<struct _, std::string>{"bracketed"}
                   = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']';

    auto time   = bracketed;              // perhaps refine
    auto source = bracketed;              // perhaps refine
    auto level  = bracketed;              // perhaps refine
    auto msg    = lexeme[*(char_ - eol)]; // perhaps refine

    auto record = rule<struct record, Record>{"record"}
                = time >> source >> level >> msg;

    auto records = *(record >> (+eol | eoi));
    auto file    = skip(blank)[records] >> eoi;
} // namespace Parser

Records ParseRecords(std::string const& fname) {
    Records records;

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file(fname);

    if (!parse(file.begin(), file.end(), Parser::file, records))
        throw std::runtime_error("Parsing failed\n");

    return records;
}

#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    for (auto& r : ParseRecords("input.txt")) {
        std::string_view payload = r.msg;
        if (payload.starts_with("Get Object: ")) {
            auto obj = json::parse(payload.substr(12));
            std::cout << " -----\n"
                      << " Level:      " << r.level              << "\n"
                      << " Time:       " << r.time               << "\n"
                      << " Source:     " << r.source             << "\n"
                      << " Type:       " << obj.at("type")       << "\n"
                      << " Event Time: " << obj.at("event_time") << "\n"
                      << " Asks:       " << obj.at("asks")       << "\n"
                      << " Bids:       " << obj.at("bids")       << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

For [input.txt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0209019ef7181ee2):

```
[2020-08-23 19:19:29.137] [exchange_tools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212350,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187624,"prev_seq_num": 111529187623,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:30.137] [exchange_fools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212351,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187625,"prev_seq_num": 111529187624,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:31.137] [exchange_pools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212352,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187626,"prev_seq_num": 111529187625,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:32.137] [exchange_mules] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212353,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187627,"prev_seq_num": 111529187626,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:33.137] [exchange_rulez] [info] Put Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212354,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187628,"prev_seq_num": 111529187627,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:34.137] [exchange_bools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212355,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187629,"prev_seq_num": 111529187628,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:35.137] [exchange_cools] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212356,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187630,"prev_seq_num": 111529187629,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:36.137] [exchange_solos] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212357,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187631,"prev_seq_num": 111529187630,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:37.137] [exchange_rolos] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212358,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187632,"prev_seq_num": 111529187631,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:38.137] [exchange_sucks] [info] Fudge Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212359,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187633,"prev_seq_num": 111529187632,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
[2020-08-23 19:19:39.137] [exchange_rocks] [info] Get Object: {"type": "update","symbol": "BTC_USDT_20l","event_id": 1598210353212360,"event_time": 1598210365978240,"exchange_time": 1598210365818,"seq_num": 111529187634,"prev_seq_num": 111529187633,"asks": [],"bids": [[11666.14, 6.752865]]}
```

Prints the expected output:

```
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:29.137
 Source:     exchange_tools
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:30.137
 Source:     exchange_fools
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:31.137
 Source:     exchange_pools
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:32.137
 Source:     exchange_mules
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:34.137
 Source:     exchange_bools
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:35.137
 Source:     exchange_cools
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:36.137
 Source:     exchange_solos
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:37.137
 Source:     exchange_rolos
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
 -----
 Level:      info
 Time:       2020-08-23 19:19:39.137
 Source:     exchange_rocks
 Type:       "update"
 Event Time: 1598210365978240
 Asks:       []
 Bids:       [[1.166614E4,6.752865E0]]
```

Comment: Lots of room to improve performance. I just realized you can use Interprocess to memory map without linking Iostreams: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4087995fd95c5bf Since performance is really not relevant now you could do without Boost Iostreams for the mapped file: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58bad83959a2640a - going the other way, avoid allocations during parse: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0462e9ef42a93767

Comment: thanks a lot, I will use this sample to push asks and bids into std::map;